# How to insert cookies into WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, webview

I'm developing an Android app using Android Studio, where I have an EditText (editText1), a Button (button1), and a WebView (webView1). I'm aiming to allow users to input a cookie value through the EditText and then apply that cookie to the WebView to load a Facebook page. I'm seeking guidance or code examples on how to achieve this programmatically in an Android Studio project.

- EditText: editText1
- Button: button1
- WebView: webView1

Steps I'm looking for:

1. Handle the Button click event
2. Retrieve the cookie value from editText1
3. Add the retrieved cookie to the WebView
4. Load a Facebook page in the WebView

I would appreciate any insights, code snippets, or recommended practices that you can provide. Thank you in advance!

I have tried couple of code generated using ChatGPT and Bard AI and also checked one question from Stack Overflow but I failed to implement that, please help

Comment: Your first step should be to come up with some code, then ask a question.

Comment: @mr.polywhirl I am not that professional, I know some basics, can you try to help me?

Comment: I know one app that is fully same to same that I am looking for.